# Understanding the derivation of a ML-estimator

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, panel-data, matrix

I have the following likelihood function:

[image]

I'm given this information about the $\Omega$ matrix ($\boldsymbol{1}$ is a $T \times 1$ vector of ones):
[image]

I would like to be able to show that the likelihood function can be rewritten to this:
[image]

I think there is a misprint in the article, hence the screen images from the article I attached are wrong, meaning that $\Omega^{-1}$ is supposed to be
$$\Omega^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}+T\sigma^2_{c}}\boldsymbol{1}(\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}'+\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}}(I_t-\boldsymbol{1}(\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}')$$

and not as stated above.

So far I've inserted the expression for $\Omega^{-1}$ in the top log-likelihood function. However, especially the last expression of the rewritten log-likelihood function bothers me, i.e. this part:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
...&
&+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}
\left(Y_i-\boldsymbol{1}\bar{Y}_i-\left(X_i-\boldsymbol{1}\bar{X}_i\right)\beta\right)'\left(Y_i-\boldsymbol{1}\bar{Y}_i-\left(X_i-\boldsymbol{1}\bar{X}_i\right)\beta\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Does anyone see the solution?

I also have this lemma, but not sure if it is to be used in the rewritting of the likelihood function:
[image]

Comment: If this is for self-study, this question should have the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe Thanks for the heads up. However, this is not "home work", but me trying to understand this derivation in order to formulate a model.